# Matlab - Timestamps create a new colum without minutes and without repetitive dates

Tags: matlab, date, timestamp

I have a question about timestamps hope you can help me.

I'm reading one timestamp column from excel to matlab using;

```
[temp, timestamps] = xlsread('2012_15min.xls', 'JAN', 'A25:A2999');
```

This column have date like this:

```
01-01-2012 00:00 
01-01-2012 00:15    
01-01-2012 00:30
01-01-2012 00:45
01-01-2012 01:00
```

(it goes on until the end of January in periods of 15 minutes)

Now I want to get a new column in matlab that keeps only year month day and hour, this data must be separated and I don't want to keep repetitive dates (e.g I don't want to get 4 dates with `01 01 2012 0` only one of that)

So I want to get:

```
01 01 2012 0
01 01 2012 1
01 01 2012 2
```

It must go until the end of January with periods of 1 hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that there is data for every hour you could construct this directly, but if you have possible missing data and you therefore need to convert from your timestamps, then some combination of `datestr`/`datenum`/`datevec` is usually the best bet.

First, convert timestamps with datevec:

```
times = datevec(timestamps); % sometimes need to also use format string
```

Then, take only the year/month/day/hour, removing repetitions:

```
[times_hours,m,n] = unique(times(:,1:4), 'rows');
```

You can use the indices in `m` to extract the matching data for those times.

If you want this converted back to some sort of string you can use `datestr` and specify format:

```
timesout = datestr(times_hours,'dd mm yyyy hh');
```

Comment: That's not working I'm getting things like 18 01 0000 hh (...)

Comment: `hh` should be `HH`, sorry. Also seems like the format of your timestamps may be such that it's not converting properly.  Try adding a format to the first datevec (something like 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM').